# Is "micronized" creatine better than regular creatine?

Tags: creatine, bodybuilding

I frequently read advertisements for "micronized" creatine which is supposedly more pure, easier to absorb, and more effective than regular creatine. Is there any validity to this claim?

Comment: "Ive been using regular monohydrate on and off for 18 or so years,works very well.I have tried a few micronised forms and find they give me nothing,no boost in strength or energy,no size.Micronised creatine is completely useless for me,only the old fashioned non micronised form gives me increased strength and muscle volume.Argue its the same, simply micronised,I dont care,for me only the original non micronised works, strange as that may seem." Maybe it is not so strange because I have experienced exactly the same thing. I am a very good responder and everytime I start to use the micronized, "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive answer I've found to this is at [BodyBuilding.com](http://www.teenbodybuilding.com/james12.htm). Essentially, standard creatine won't make you retain water like micronized creatine, and the standard creatine is used continuously, whereas the micronized creatine should be used in a load-maintain-unload cycle.

The lack of water retention will change the look of the muscle you are building to be less soft if you're using standard creatine, as well as lowering your weight/size.

Comment: The article compares liquid creatine and micronized creatine. As the article mentions how new liquid creatine is, I doubt this is the regular creatine, the question asks for.

Answer (score 4):

[An answer to another question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/463/3941) lead me to an the article [Conquering creatine myths with science](http://www.nutritionexpress.com/article+index/vitamins+supplements+a-z/creatine/showarticle.aspx?articleid=208) which also talks about other forms of creatine:

> Harris showed that the vast majority of creatine powder consumed is absorbed -- about 95% of the dose.
>   […]
>   Special treatments and "delivery systems," such as micronization, effervescent powder, or sublingual sprays have never been shown to produce more retention or absorption than creatine powder.

The Author of [Creatine: How Much Should You Be Taking?](http://schwarzenegger.com/fitness/post/creatine-how-much-should-you-be-taking) on Schwarzenegger.com agrees

> Creatine monohydrate is incredibly well-studied—and nearly every study referenced in this article utilized CM. It’s one of the most stable forms of creatine in solution, it’s not degraded during normal digestion, and 99 percent is either absorbed by muscle tissue or excreted through sweat or urine[41-42]. Other forms of creatine may be more soluble, but that has nothing to do with effectiveness. Creatine monohydrate is simply your best—and cheapest—choice.

So it seems that you really don't need any special creatine as the absorption rates of standard creatine are extremely high anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ive been using regular monohydrate on and off for 18 or so years,works very well.I have tried a few micronised forms and find they give me nothing,no boost in strength or energy,no size.Micronised creatine is completely useless for me,only the old fashioned non micronised form gives me increased strength and muscle volume.Argue its the same, simply micronised,I dont care,for me only the original non micronised works, strange as that may seem.

Answer (score 0):

Something most people are not aware of is the fact that in order to take advantage of creatine, the creatine powder **must be dissolved** in water. For this, you simply mix the creatine in your glass of water and mix until it gets completely dissolved.

Micronized creatine will dissolved faster than regular, and this is why it is the preferred option.

Mixing your creatine on warm water will speed up the creatine getting dissolved. If the creatine does not get fully dissolved and you drink it, your body will not absorb it.

Here is a good video comparing micronized creatine to that of regular. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OJvXzP39rg

Comment: Can you provide a reference for creatine needing to be dissolved to be effective? That's a pretty important caveat if true, but in my experience it's not a widely accepted "truth".

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Creatine_supplements&oldid=773955903#Micronized_creatine ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170429211256/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatine_supplements)) :

> Since 2011, products containing micronised creatine monohydrate have been marketed as sports supplements. Micronization involves reducing the size of creatine particles to between 0.36 and 9.08 μm in diameter.[37] Purported benefits of these products include easier mixing into drink format for supplementation and faster absorption of the creatine into the bloodstream. While reducing particle size may make powdered creatine easier to dissolve in water due to exposure of a greater total particle surface area to collisions with solvent molecules (increasing the rate of reaction), it cannot change its overall solubility. **There is no evidence that micronized creatine monohydrate offers any physiological benefit over other forms or can reduce the risk of gastrointestinal side effects**.

Unfortunately the claim is unreferenced.