# Can creatine and citrus be combined?

Tags: nutrition, supplements, creatine

Many creatine distributors, health forums, etc. recommend avoiding mixing creatine with citrus juices, as supposedly the citric acid could combine with the creatine to produce creatinine, which isn't a useful substance for strength training and bodybuilding.

However, it occurs to me that stomach acid is stronger and more acidic than any juice that one is likely to drink.

So, is there something specific about citric acid and creatine that would not apply to stomach acid, or is the creatine/citrus warning a myth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This advice doesn't pass simple common sense.  Creatinine is a toxin used as a proxy to detect kidney problems, It almost certainly would never have made it to store shelves if it broke down to creatinine on contact with acid.

An article entitled [Conquering creatine myths with science](http://www.nutritionexpress.com/article+index/vitamins+supplements+a-z/creatine/showarticle.aspx?articleid=208) simply boils it down simply as follows:

> - Myth: Creatine is instantly destroyed by acid, either in the stomach or in juice.
> - Fact: Creatine easily survives stomach acid and can be mixed with acidic beverages if you consume them shortly after mixing.

The myth *probably* began with some creatine producers differentiating themselves by claiming their formula protects the creatine from stomach acid, thereby increasing absorption rates [citation needed].  At any rate, the idea that citric acid has an affect that stomach acid does not is false.